# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code which give the error unterminated string literal.
What is that error. Here is a code in which i am working.
I check console and the error is in `$('#mydiv').append('\` in this line.
Any suggestion. Thanks.

```
$('#mydiv').append('\
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="t1">\
<TR>\
<TD class="tr1 td8"><P class="p13 ft13">T E S T</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr1 td9"><P class="p2 ft6">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr1 td10"><P class="p14 ft13">RESULT</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr1 td11"><P class="p2 ft13">Cutoff</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr1 td11"><P class="p2 ft13">Patient</P></TD>\
</TR>\
<TR>\
<TD class="tr4 td12"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr4 td13"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr4 td14"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr4 td15"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr4 td15"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
</TR>\                         
                       ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this:

```
$('#mydiv').append('\
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="t1">\
<TR>\
<TD class="tr1 td8"><P class="p13 ft13">T E S T</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr1 td9"><P class="p2 ft6">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr1 td10"><P class="p14 ft13">RESULT</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr1 td11"><P class="p2 ft13">Cutoff</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr1 td11"><P class="p2 ft13">Patient</P></TD>\
</TR>\
<TR>\
<TD class="tr4 td12"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr4 td13"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr4 td14"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr4 td15"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
<TD class="tr4 td15"><P class="p2 ft14">&nbsp;</P></TD>\
</TR>');
```

The penultimate line is not escaped so the error.

Comment: This is not working I check the console and error is here `<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="t1">\ `

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of spaces after the `\` on the penultimate line, so you have failed to escape the new line there.